How would Merfolk make a solar oven
My merfolk species has a civilization that lives in towns floating on the oceans surface. The merfolk have legs, and can stay out of water for ~45 mins before drying out (they breath through their skin). Cooked food is a rare commodity, similar to the human appreciation of caviar. I was thinking the floating towns could have an above water section with a solar oven that they could use to cook with. This could lead into metallurgy, but how would they make the oven in the first place? I was thinking something like a solar death ray. There are multiple mermaid civilizations, and they do trade with each other, but they couldn’t use open fires due to both an instinctual fear and a risk of drying out.

This appears to be lacking research. Simple solar cookers have existed forever and use principles that scale all the way to metallurgy. You are obligated to perform research before asking questions (see [ask]). What about existing solar cooking solutions doesn't solve your problem?

@JBH Yeah good point, as your link describes all he needs is some aluminum foil and he'll be well on his way to metallurgy.

@causative It's better to remain silent and be thought a fool than to speak and remove all doubt. The point of my comment was that the OP had done no research, which is obligatory. Natural mirrors exist.

@JBH If you believe that aluminum foil, the NREL's high flux solar furnace, or a wet salt flat are things the pre-metallurgy merfolk could use to make a solar oven, that belongs in an answer.

@causative What I believe is the OP didn't do their due diligence.

@JBH This would be more convincing if your "due diligence" did not involve aluminum foil and then space-age solar furnace technology. You also claimed solar cookers have existed "forever," but they are first attested in 1767.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@causative although I agree with your point, I would recommend not to use sarcasm. It can too easily lead to an escalating scenario, as people are more likely to react defensively.

@Trioxidane We should give a friendlier welcome to new question contributors.

@causative I fully agree, though it can backfire if you push the offenders into defensive positions. It is hard enough for people to admit a mistake or change. Piling on disdain or similar often elicits a more emotional response, which distress can lead to lashing out, and refusing to (start) any change in their behaviour. That is why I suggest a cooperative stance where possible.

I would question the instinctive fear of fire. Its not exactly high on the list of dangers that naturally occur underwater.

I think the OP should share what these floating towns look like, since it will give some idea about technology level/materials science.

@Yorik they’re quite complex given the resources they have access to, essentially large rafts with homes hanging underneath, chained to the (relatively shallow) ocean floor with several very thick ropes tied to large coral stones.

made of what; what kinds of fasteners etc.

@Yorik they are made from kelp intertwined to form ropes around 8 inches in diameter. They are pre-metallurgy.

@LazyLizard it has to do with their origins, they are directly derived from humans and are also hesitant of them. My merfolk were directly crafted by the God of the Sea from drowned humans.

@JBH your "natural mirror" only work for low angle reflection, since they are just mirage refractions effects. you can;t use that to make a solar oven its not a material.

@John I'm not entirely convinced. People (myself included) bake like potatoes swimming in a swimming pool, much less the ocean. The goal of this site isn't scientific perfection, it's believability (we're dealing with merfolk, after all), so yeah... I'm not convinced it wouldn't be a perfectly reasonable solution.

@JBHh you would get sunburned from the light anyway, he goal of a solar oven is to conventrate the light, which you cant do with a mirage based mirror.

Ice.
They're OK with the cold right? I mean they live in the ocean, so they should be.
A piece of glacier can be carved - pick a bit with few bubbles, then mounted on a rotating frame which allows it to tilt to track the sun.
A lens can be fashioned to allow focusing the light and heat as wanted (on a sunny day).
This can be tested yourself on a winter's day at home - with a bucket (and gloves).
There's a nicely illustrative video by "Give It A Grow" of the principle.

Good idea, wrong approach. You carve the glacier - and then cover it with some reflecting, into a parabolic mirror, focusing it all into the center. There on a pole, the heat goes into 550 ° C - enough to cook- or keep a charcoal driven melting process going. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concentrated_solar_power

water (including ice) absorbs infrared a lot.Not that it will not work, but the efficiency will be at least halved compared to glass

Quartz or water lenses
It's challenging to make a mirror without metallurgy. The earliest mirrors were likely basins of water. Of course, as water must be level, these are not suitable to make a solar furnace with. Later mirrors were made of polished obsidian. It's difficult to find numbers for the reflectivity of polished obsidian, but from pictures, polished obsidian does not seem to actually reflect much incoming light. It mostly looks like just a very dark surface so that what little light it does reflect stands out by contrast. So it's doubtful that you could make a solar furnace from polished obsidian.
After that, mirrors were made from polished bronze. But you can't get polished bronze until you already have metallurgy, so that's also out. Glass mirrors of course are not possible either, since you can't melt glass without a source of heat in the first place.
But there are certain glass-like rocks that occur naturally. Diamonds are very sparkly, but they are rare and very difficult to cut and polish for people who don't even have fire yet. In mineralogy, diamonds have adamantine lustre, a property they share with cerussite, zircon, and cubic zirconia. Zircon and cubic zirconia are very hard and thus difficult to cut and polish, but cerussite (white lead ore) is soft.
The best of all would be quartz, though, which has a vitreous lustre. Quartz is transparent and common. The merfolk could use other stones to polish and shape this into a curved glass-like lens, and use that to focus light. It wouldn't be suitable as a mirror unless they also have something to make a silvery backing, but lenses can make a solar furnace too.
Or they might find and polish some rare silvery minerals. Some of these silver minerals, such as canfieldite, occur naturally and have a shiny appearance; perhaps an appropriate mirror could be made of them. It would be challenging to gather enough of these minerals for a big mirror, though.
A good alternative to quartz would be water lenses. It is possible to start a fire with nothing but a clear plastic bag filled with water. Your merfolk don't have plastic bags, but there may be fish or something with an organ that has a clear membrane, such as a swim bladder. They could fill that membrane with water and use it as a lens.
Perhaps the cornea of a whale or giant squid could be used as a ready-made lens as well.
Also, don't forget insulation
Keeping the heat from escaping your oven is just as important as focusing the sunlight. The first solar oven, made by Saussure in 1767, didn't even have any focusing lenses or mirrors; it was simply a little insulated greenhouse, black on the inside to absorb the heat. This alone was sufficient to cook some foods.
To insulate the oven you first want an airtight seal over the top with a clear window so the sunlight can come in. Sheets of mica might be suitable; though they aren't very clear they naturally form in ready-made sheets that are convenient for a window. In present day they're used in the windows of coal stoves. A better, clearer window would be quartz, though it would be more difficult to find and shape a large sheet of it. Or perhaps a transparent organic membrane taken from fish would work.
Bone, fur, and blubber can insulate the sides and seal the gaps.
Since the lenses the merfolk can practically make would be fairly small, and you want a large collecting area, you'll want a large array of many lenses focused through the window of your insulated oven.

I was about to suggest the last one. Use a Leviathan scale, they're extremely resistant and near perfect mirrors once polished. The ones near the eye have a special curve that is very useful to concentrate light to a specific point. There are merfolks in this universe, so OP can easily make up a creature that has a body part that does exactly what is needed for a solar oven.

If it's done with a lens of the eye of a huge squid, this would add to the attractive rarity of the food, since the lens would be hard to get and wouldn't last very long. It's also pretty plausible that someone playing with squid parts would notice that they can focus light, producing patterns, then smoke, then fire. This is more likely than someone working out that a water lens or polished stone would do the trick from first principles, and then going to great lengths to construct such an object.

Would nacre be reflective enough? The inside of an oyster shell is white-ish, which suggests it reflects a large share of the spectrum, and already has some curve to it, getting us close to a parabolic mirror. Folks wisdom would be that shouldn't leave your oyster shells in the Sun, lest they set the island on fire, and from there on it's not a big leap to assume some adventurous spirit would experiment with them... if they're reflective enough, that is.

Everyone focused on lenses and mirrors, but:
Double Frame Challenge
First off, they would not start with an oven.  The first cooking would be either roasting or frying.  The frying could be of the "fry an egg on the sidewalk" style.  This doesn't work on many foods, but eggs don't need high temperatures to cook.
Second, they would almost certainly use fire.  Yes, it is dangerous and fearful.  This is why cooked food is very rare.  But on a floating island, there are probably holes in the floor to let the cook drop into the water if he/she gets in trouble.  Roasting would be holding the food on a stick in the fire.  Frying could be from mounting something like a piece of slate over your fire pit and cooking on that.
It also occurs to me that, on a floating island, you could rig the underpinnings to be quickly removable to sink anything having trouble (as in on fire).

a lot of seafaring cultures just make slab of clay, a box of sand or a flat rock to start their fires on. of course you can just start a fire on a solid block of wood, which will not sustain a fire, if it somehow does chatch you just push it in to the water, thats what the Bajau do.  Seapeople might use large seashells of course that would quikly lead to some understanding of chemistry as they make quicklime, which would lead to them learning to make glass a LOT sooner.

The hardest part of building a solar oven will be acquiring a reflective material. Some type of refined glass or metal would be ideal, but those are difficult to produce without fire. Besides that I can think of two options:

Find naturally occurring mirror-like objects. For example, certain types of fish have scales with reflective properties. The merfolk could harvest those scales and stick them to a wooden board to build a makeshift mirror.

Use water to make a magnifying glass. All you have to do is form the
water into a convex lens shape. Typically this is done using plastic
or glass, but any solid transparent material will work. Some kind of
preserved membrane sack harvested from a sea creature might do the
trick.



You can't escape fire, you can only make it rare.
To expand on Davids idea, they originally used fire, mostly in large sea shells, as a side effect of that they made lime and soda ash. Sand boxes are often used by humans as a way to have fire on wooden boats. this could eventually lead to the creation of glass, and with the right shells mirrors from heavy trace metals in the shells. They might never realize the thin layer of metal could be made into other useful stuffsince it is produced in incredibly tiny amounts. These would be used to make solar ovens. Now they make furnaces on isolated islands to make glass, these can be right near the beach to they can stay wet. Of course they probably figuire out clay as well doing this. All this could be invented without true metallurgy. they would need ot make a lot of glass stuff before they intent a solar oven however as miror glass is hard and requires a lot of glass making skill first.
things to consider:
Mercury, your most likely mirror metal, is really toxic to make, at least the metal is. So running back to the ocean to stay wet might be the only thing keeping them from being poisoned.
They are going to be using a lot of fire to get to this point to they will liekly have a fire using culture even if they switch to ovens for cooking. You can't get to glass and mirrors without fire. Cooking means fire. The only way they could cook without fire is going to lava feilds which is way WAY more dangeous than a tiny fire.
They could make their glass from dried and cleaned glass sponges, which will be purer than most sands meaning they can get clear glass faster. They might discover this by using larger flat glass sponges as  fire containers or wide vase shaped ones as ventelated fire covers. They may even be sing them as wicks for whale oil lanterns. They also make for good fireproof insulation.

Because of their sensitivity to heat and the impact of the reflective properties of water, your mermaids would have a natural understanding of conditions that concentrate heat on the water surface. (I got a sunburn when I was 10 years old that I will NEVER forget - thought I was safe because I was in the water at the time.) I imagine that they would start off with dried foods (seaweed and fish?) and naturally progress from there. For basic heating, the best place to be is probably right at the surface of the water, where the sunlight is already being bounced in from all directions. Therefore, they could have had this technology with a very minimal structure floating on the water surface. I really like the thought of building on their strengths with this - they don’t have fire, but they understand the properties of reflective surfaces inside out, forwards, backwards, and sideways.

Support a clear membrane such as a plastic film at the edges with a ring. Pour clear water into it. It will sag in the centre to give a lens-like shape. Pour more water in to get the focus you need. If your sun goes overhead (or nearly so) it will focus the sun below it just in time for lunch.
If the water surface was flat and your water was clear enough, you could use an air-filled concave lens: perhaps two membranes at either end of a tube. This could be used with oblique illumination. But the light would be travelling through more water, and the more IR would be absorbed.

Merfolk could use glass made by fire/melting sand, or something similar using focused light with mirrors/some other reflective thing; or they could do something similar to a grill or pizza oven where they make an oven from clay and make a fire in a pit below it.  That way, if they could start the fire quick enough and return to water periodically, and heat from the fire would only come from the opening for food above it, probably an opening below it for oxygen/tending to the fire, and a chimney above it.

As an alternative to glass (suggested by @causative and 42gasp) to make the window of a basic greenhouse-style solar oven, the merfolk could use glass sponge spicules.
These are flexible and according to some research they conduct light similar to human-made fiber optics (though it's unclear to me from the articles if that's just in the IR or the whole spectrum).
The merfolk could harvest them from the deep (or even possibly farm them, if their civilization is not completely nomadic hunter-gatherer).

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
